# Connect Image with Text using SVG Lines

Tags: html, css, svg, positioning

i am currently struggling with positioning in CSS.
There are three buzzwords in the header that are to be connected to specific points in a graphic using lines.
How do I make the ratio of the text to the respective areas on the image match even with smaller viewports (Should work for Viewports > 992px)

I appreciate all suggestions and help!

[Screendesign example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfcVd.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] of the problem. We can't work with a raster image alone.

Comment: I suggest wrapping the text and image in an svg, that way the ratio will remain the same